# gtk# CellRendererCombo in TreeView

Tags: c#, grid, gtk#, gtktreeview, cellrenderer

I want to have a `Gtk.TreeView` that has for the first Column to be a ComboBox, in which I'll be able to select the Value I want the first Column to be. Here's my code below.

```
        Gtk.TreeViewColumn compteColumn = new TreeViewColumn();
        Gtk.CellRendererCombo compteCellCombo = new CellRendererCombo();
        compteColumn.PackStart(compteCellCombo, true);
        compteColumn.AddAttribute(compteCellCombo, "text", 0);
        compteColumn.Title = "Compte Name";
        compteCellCombo.Editable = true;
```

I tried to searched for the `Gtk.CellRendererCombo` attributes in the internet, but I found nothing worthy, I tried a few of them:

- text
- text-column
- model
- editable

But nothing seems to work, as for the "text" attribute it generates this kind of message:

```
(eAppGtk:2528): Gtk-WARNING **: gtkliststore.c:608: Unable to convert from GtkSharpValue to gchararray


(eAppGtk:2528): Gtk-WARNING **: gtkliststore.c:608: Unable to convert from gchararray to gint
```

A good insight on what is going wrong would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What I thought should be attribute set by a string in the `Gtk.TreeViewColumn.AddAttribute(cell, attribute, columnIndex)`, could be set by the C# Properties' fashion. The Column Index in this situation is the Property TextColumn.

The rest should speak for itself in the code below:

```
this.compteComboBox = new CompteComboBox(this.window.CompteManager, new ComboBox());

Gtk.TreeViewColumn compteColumn = new TreeViewColumn();
Gtk.CellRendererCombo compteCellCombo = new CellRendererCombo();
compteColumn.PackStart(compteCellCombo, true);
compteColumn.Title = "Compte Name";
compteCellCombo.TextColumn = 0;
compteCellCombo.Editable = true;
compteCellCombo.Edited += OnEdited;
compteCellCombo.HasEntry = true;
compteCellCombo.Model = this.compteComboBox.ComboBox.Model;
compteCellCombo.Text = this.compteComboBox.ComboBox.ActiveText;
```